# CSS -ms-grid-columns syntax showing errors in VS Code with extension

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I'm using the [Live Sass Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass) extension on VS code, which automatically adds CSS vendor prefixes.

Here is my code in SCSS:

```
.card {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
```

It has been compiled into this in CSS:

```css
.card {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[2];
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  -ms-grid-rows: 300px 1fr auto;
      grid-template-rows: 300px 1fr auto;
```

However, Visual Studio Code displays this issue: `-ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[2];`

Is this incorrect syntax for -ms-... selectors?

Whatever the correct command is, the styles.css file will always update with the incorrect one when I save my scss files.

What can I do.. is it correct?